# How to drop rows that have duplicate pairs of values in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a Pandas DataFrame and would like to remove rows that have duplicate pairs in two columns. Here's an example displaying what I mean:

```
    col0    col1    col2
0    0       1       0
1    1       2       1
2    0       3       0
3    4       4       6
4    3       5       1
5    0       6       0
```

Let's say that I want to delete duplicates according to value pairs on `col0` and `col2`. As you can see in this toy example, rows `0`, `2`, and `5` have duplicates of `(0, 0)` pairs, and I would like to remove the duplicate rows and only keep one.

Is there a way that I could do this efficiently? I've tried taking a look into [pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) but it seems to behave slightly differently from what I expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col0','col2']) does exactly what you want, so what is the problem?

Comment: @eugen I think OP's focus is on value pair. df.drop_duplicates won't regard ['B', 'A'] and ['A', 'B'] as duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can pass columns based on which you want to drop duplicates.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [4, 4, 6], [3, 5, 1], [0, 6, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'])

print(df.drop_duplicates(['col0', 'col2']))
```

output:

```
    col0    col1    col2
0      0       1    0
1      1       2    1
3      4       4    6
4      3       5    1
```

Comment: Shoudn't the zeroth row drop as well according to what op is asking?

Comment: What if the pairs are made up of two different values, such as [1, 2] and [2, 1], which can be regarded as a duplicate value pair (set)? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu The thing you are asking is not logically correct. You have two columns `col1` and `col2`. Then values in this columns for example 1,2 and 2,1 are different. 
You cant swap those values around as data perspective. If so it doesn't make sense to have two different columns.

Comment: My bad for not expressing myself clearly. For instance `e1 = pd.DataFrame({'firm1':[1, 2, 3, 4],'firm2': [2, 1, 5, 6],'deal': [4, 4, 6, 7]} )`, in this example I want to keep only 1 of the rows which share the same value pair/set, hence only 1 of the first 2 rows. Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

Below will do the trick:

```
data = [[0,1,0],[1,2,1],[0,3,0],[4,4,6],[3,5,1],[0,6,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col0', 'col1','col2'])
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col0','col2']))
```

```
   col0  col1  col2
0     0     1     0
1     1     2     1
3     4     4     6
4     3     5     1
```

Comment: please run your code its output is not matching with one mentioned in your answer. Are you missing something in your answer?